# Unable to create a Contact item in List Manager

Tags: xdb, contact-facets

I have installed a Sitecore 9 Update 1 and using Solr 6.6.2 for our ContentSearch. However when I've tried to create a contact on an empty List under List Manager but I am getting an error. Below is the details I've found on the log file. Any idea if there something I missed on my installation?

> ERROR [Sitecore Services]: HTTP POST
>   URL http://sc9u1/sitecore/api/lists/8aee5dca-bc25-471a-a893-3524e58b48ce/contacts
>
> Exception Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException:
>   {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An error
>   occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'ContactsController'. Make sure that the controller has a
>   parameterless public
>   constructor.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"
>
> at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)
>         at Sitecore.XConnect.Web.DependencyInjection.WebApiServiceControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)
>         at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage
>   request)
>         at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"Message":"An
>   error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Type
>   'Sitecore.XConnect.Web.Controllers.ContactsController' does not have a
>   default
>   constructor","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","StackTrace":"
>         at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)
>         at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)
>         at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type controllerType, Func1& activator)at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)"}}
>         at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func1 taskFactory)
>    at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func1
>   taskFactory)
>         at Sitecore.ListManagement.XConnect.SubscriptionService.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0(IXdbContext
>   client)
>         at Sitecore.ListManagement.XConnect.XdbRequestPerformer.RequestWithRetry(Action1
>   action, String actionMessage)
>         at Sitecore.ListManagement.XConnect.SubscriptionService.CreateSubscribedContact(Guid
>   listId, String identifier, String source, String firstName, String
>   lastName, String email)
>         at Sitecore.ListManagement.Services.Repositories.ListSubscriptionsStore.CreateSubscribedContact(Guid
>   listId, ContactDataModel contactDataModel)
>         at Sitecore.ListManagement.Services.Controllers.ContactsController.CreateEntity(Guid
>   listId, ContactDataModel contactDataModel)
>         at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
>         at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)
>         at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)

Comment: can you verify connection to xconnect, connection to databases ?

Comment: That typically means an error resolving one of the dependencies for that controller in XConnect. So typically something with the search or data providers. Try increasing the logging level in XConnect to get find extra details on what might be going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by doing the following. Thanks to this post which I also refer. https://blog.wesleylomax.co.uk/2017/11/01/solrcore-initialization-failures-xconnect-sitecore-9/

1. Restart (SiteName).xconnect Site in IIS.
2. Stop Solr.
3. Delete the core "sitecore_xdb" in the file system of Solr.
4. Add the core "sitecore_xdb" folder again with the default items in /conf and data in the file system.
5. Add the core again on the https://localhost:8983/solr/#/~cores/ and map the create folder.
6. Start Solr.
7. Run C:\inetpub\wwwroot\(SiteName).xconnect\App_data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\XConnectSearchIndexer.exe

After doing the things above I am now able to create contact on List Manager.